# Magento2 - Same Product is appending twice from product review page

Tags: magento2

I'm facing a issue when user is `LogIn` and adds `One` product to cart and `Logout` and adds same product to cart  from category page when user `Login` again two products gets append in cart.Old cart quantity has to be updated with newer one

Answer (score 1):

@Vinodkumar

This is default Magento's functionality when you add product any products to cart and then logout then when you again add product to cart & login with same login details Magento will merge both the quotes into one, so that you are seeing same product with 2 qty, you can also check with different products for login before & again login with same user.

Its Cart Merge functionality of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Cart is working based on cookie, you can clear your browser `cookie/cache` or try activity in new browser or incognito.

two different users never will use same computer & browser, so that issue does not normally happen in live sites.

You can try this:
Fix the issue using `"Clear Persistence on Sign Out" >> Yes`

Magento Admin Path:

```
Stores >> Configuration >> CUSTOMERS >> Persistent Shopping Cart >> General Options >> Clear Persistence on Sign Out : **No to Yes**
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the issue im facing instead of updating the cart it is inserting

[image]